# How to iterate over a sequence in Common Lisp with loop?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Previously I had been using "being the elements of" feature of loop to iterate over a sequence of an unknown type. I just found out that "being the elements of" is not provided in every implementation of Common Lisp and am wondering if there is any clean way to iterate over a sequence using loop. The best solution I have been able to come with is to coerce the sequence to a list and then iterate over that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, `LOOP` does not provide such a feature directly. If your `LOOP` implementation is extensible (which the standard says nothing about, too), you might be able to implement such a feature.

`LOOP` has clauses to iterate over lists - `for item in list` - and a clause to iterate over a vector - `for e across vector` - note that strings are also vectors, one-dimensional arrays. But not both together.

Otherwise use `MAP` or `MAP-INTO` to iterate over sequences.

The `ITERATE` macro provides such a feature: `for i in-sequence seq`.